# MKMapView and viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear using Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I have a ViewController with a MapView, the controller is initialized by a segue specified in the storyboard. The MapView is connected (via Storyboard) to a property in the controller.

---

.h file

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *locationMapView;
```

I am using a method to center the MapView to a specific region:

```
- (void)centerMapView
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude), 1000, 1000);
    [self.locationMapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

    NSLog(@"size height: %f",self.locationMapView.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"size width: %f",self.locationMapView.frame.size.width);
}
```

Calling this method from `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear` does nothing for the first time, but centers it correctly for the second time the View is loaded.
The Log output is always:

```
size height: 0.000000
size width: 0.000000
```

When called in `viewDidAppear` the MapView is centered and the output size is correct:

```
size height: 400.000000
size width: 320.000000
```

I guess the size values mean that the view is not yet initialized in `viewDidLoad`/`viewWill` appear, this might be unrelated to the my problem with setting the region.

I am wondering, if it is really not possible to set the region of the MapView in `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear` so the user does not see a changing of the region.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you say that you tried this in viewWillAppear as well?  If not, try it in there.

Comment: I did try that without success

Answer (score 0):

The view size issue probably is unrelated to your problem with setting the region.

The key question: when is `DetailViewController`'s `geoPoint` property set, relative to when its view gets loaded? If `viewDidLoad` runs before you set that property (presumably from `prepareForSegue:sender:` in another view controller), `geoPoint` will be nil (zero) when you try to center the map, so it won't center it correctly. (And it works the second time because the instance of `DetailViewController` already exists and has its `geoPoint` from the previous time.)

You might consider calling your `centerMapView` method from a custom setter for your `geoPoint` property -- that way you're guaranteed that it'll happen once the view controller has the appropriate data, which will still be before it appears so there won't be a visible map transition.

Comment: You are right, the `geoPoint` is set in a `prepareForSegue:sender:` from another controller.
However, the calling the `centerMapView` from a custom initializer to `geoPoint` did not help. I log the latitude and longitude of `geoPoint` in my `centerMapView` and it is always set to the correct value, even when called from `viewDidLoad`.